# Manipulate columns based on lagged values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In R, I'd like to perform a mutate to fill in NA values of multiple columns (both x and y).

```
data <- data.table(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),
                   x = c(1, 3, NA, NA, NA),
                   y = c(2, 4, NA, NA, NA))
```

| year | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 1 | 2 |
| 2011 | 3 | 4 |
| 2012 | NA | NA |
| 2013 | NA | NA |
| 2014 | NA | NA |

These calculations however are dependent on the lagged values of the other column. For values where year is greater than 2011,

- `x = x(previous row) + y(previous row)`
- `y = x(2 previous rows) + y(2 previous rows)`

The intended output then would be

| year | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 1 | 2 |
| 2011 | 3 | 4 |
| 2012 | 7 | 3 |
| 2013 | 10 | 7 |
| 2014 | 17 | 10 |

This is the code I ran:

```
data %>% 
 mutate(
   x = case_when(
     year > 2011 ~ lag(x, 1) + lag(y, 1),
     TRUE ~ x),
   y = case_when(
     year > 2011 ~ lag(x, 2) + lag(y, 2),
     TRUE ~ y))
```

However, this does not work because no matter the order they are calculated in, the mutate of each variable is dependent on an NA value that has not been calculated yet (so the value for x in 2013 cannot be calculated because the mutate for y calculating the value for 2012 has not been performed yet, but the reverse is the case as well where y needs the x value from 2012). My dataset is much larger than this and has a more complex calculation involving a third variable that is interdependent in a similar way as well.

Is there a way to perhaps run these mutates concurrently or any other solution to get around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is that `lag()` is vectorized, but each row depends on the result of the former one so we can't use a vectorized approach here, but need to caclulate row by row.

One way to do this is with a recursive function taking the `data.frame` as input and returning the filled `data.frame` after several iterations.

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- tibble(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), x=c(1, 3, NA, NA, NA), y=c(2, 4, NA, NA, NA))

calc_row <- function(dat, run = nrow(dat)) {

  omit_na_dat <- na.omit(dat)
  
  if (nrow(omit_na_dat) == run) {
    return(dat)
  }
  
  row_idx <- nrow(omit_na_dat)
  
  new_x = omit_na_dat[row_idx, ][["x"]] + omit_na_dat[row_idx, ][["y"]]
  new_y = omit_na_dat[row_idx - 1, ][["x"]] + omit_na_dat[row_idx - 1, ][["y"]]
  new_year = omit_na_dat[row_idx, ][["year"]] + 1
  
  dat <- rows_update(dat, tibble(year = new_year,
                                 x = new_x,
                                 y = new_y),
                     by = "year"
                     )
  calc_row(dat, run = run)
}

calc_row(dat)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    year     x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2010     1     2
#> 2  2011     3     4
#> 3  2012     7     3
#> 4  2013    10     7
#> 5  2014    17    10
```

Update:

Lets assume there is another column `z` that we want to update but based on the current value (and not the lagged value from the rows before) then we can modify the approach as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), x=c(1, 3, NA, NA, NA), y=c(2, 4, NA, NA, NA), z = 1)

calc_row <- function(dat, run = nrow(dat)) {
  
  omit_na_dat <- na.omit(dat)
  
  if (nrow(omit_na_dat) == run) {
    return(dat)
  }
  
  row_idx <- nrow(omit_na_dat)
  
  new_x = omit_na_dat[row_idx, ][["x"]] + omit_na_dat[row_idx, ][["y"]]
  new_y = omit_na_dat[row_idx - 1, ][["x"]] + omit_na_dat[row_idx - 1, ][["y"]]
  new_year = omit_na_dat[row_idx, ][["year"]] + 1
  new_z = dat[row_idx + 1, ][["z"]] + 1
  
  dat <- rows_update(dat, tibble(year = new_year,
                                 x = new_x,
                                 y = new_y,
                                 z = new_z),
                     by = "year")
  
  calc_row(dat, run = run)
}

calc_row(dat)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>    year     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2010     1     2     1
#> 2  2011     3     4     1
#> 3  2012     7     3     2
#> 4  2013    10     7     2
#> 5  2014    17    10     2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I'm adapting it to my data, and in one of the equations I need to add a variable in a current row as well (not a lagged one). So for example, if I had a third row z and wanted x = x(previous row) + y(previous row) + z (current row). I'm having issues trying to reference the current row in the function. Any thoughts?

Comment: @cdiz without an example its hard to say, but please see my updated answer where I just make up a variable `z` that we want to updated based on the value in the current row.

Comment: Logically this made sense to me as well, but with my dataset it gives an error of C stack usage being too close to the limit and "no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart"

Answer (score 3):

The computation of `x` is like a ***Fibonacci sequence*** with initial values 4 (`y[2]`) and 3 (`x[2]`). And `y` is just the lagged `x`.

```r
fib <- function(a1, a2, len){
  seq <- c(a1, a2)
  for(i in 3:len) {
    seq[i] <- seq[i-1] + seq[i-2]
  }
  return(seq)
}

fib(4, 3, 5)
# [1]  4  3  7 10 17
```

```r
df %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(row_number() > 2, fib(y[2], x[2], n()), x),
         y = ifelse(row_number() > 2, lag(x), y))

# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#    year     x     y
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2010     1     2
# 2  2011     3     4
# 3  2012     7     3
# 4  2013    10     7
# 5  2014    17    10
```